# SET OPERATORS UNIION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any possibility of union 2 columns of different datatypes in oracle sql?

I have CHAR datatype column in one table and a number in another table..

```
SELECT EMP_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
UNION 
SELECT TO_NUMBER(CUST_NAME) 
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

EMP_ID IS THE NUMBER DATATYPE AND CUST_NAME IS VARCHAR2 DATATYPE.
IAM GETTING "invalid number" error ...

Comment: Please do not SHOUT, it is considered rude to type everything in uppercase.

Comment: Cast one of them to the type of the other one.

Comment: If you know what you want to do then you (*should*) have already tried something. Please add an error message you have or describe what issue you currently have. SO is not for yes/no questions/answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes; convert number to string.

```
select char_column from table_1
union all
select to_char(number_column) from table_2
```

---

Maybe it would work vice versa as well, but - not all strings can be converted to numbers.